# Partial textarea editing, between the quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<textarea>Name ""</textarea>`
How can I put the cursor this way when clicking? Name "CURSOR", and prohibit editing placeholder name and quotes.

Comment: Why not a `label` or `placeholder`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do this. How about using different inputs instead?

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" placeholder="Name">
```

That having been said, I've had a play around and have come up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/a6t3qwb5/